# Autocomplete can't filling textbox

Tags: java, jsp, autocomplete

I have autocomplete but not filling the textbox
My Java code:

```
 String string=request.getParameter("queryString");
 try
 {
  String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/path";
  Connection con;
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
  String sql = "SELECT name FROM jsample WHERE name LIKE '%"+
                string+"%' LIMIT 10";
  Statement stm = con.createStatement();
  stm.executeQuery(sql);
  ResultSet rs= stm.getResultSet();
  while (rs.next ())
  {
   out.println(
     "<li onclick='fill("+rs.getString("name")+
     ");'>"+rs.getString("name")+"</li>"
   );
  }
 } catch(Exception e) {
   out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
 }
```

This is my script to get values:

```
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function lookup(inputString)
   {
    if(inputString.length == 0)
    {
     $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
     $.post(
      "states.jsp", 
      {queryString: ""+inputString+""},
      function(data)
      {
       if(data.length >0)
       {
        $('#suggestions').show();
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
       }
      });
    }
   }
   function fill(thisValue)
   {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
   }
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-au.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <form>
    <div>
     <h3><font color="red">Name Selected</states></font></h3><br />
     Enter Name from database to see autocomplete
     <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" 
      onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
    </div>
    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
     <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList"></div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
```

This is my scripts for showing the autocomplete.

How to fill the values to textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things to change:

1.) Add id to your `<li>`

```
out.println("<li onclick='fill("+rs.getString("name")+");' id='"+rs.getString("name")+"' >" + rs.getString("name") + "</li>");
```

2.) Add `$('#inputString').val(thisValue.innerHTML);` in your `function fill`.

3.) Remove `onblur="fill();"` from `input` tag it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

Because the returned data is dynamic data so you can not capture such events. Please refer to the following link
[In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: thanks for answer can you give me example the code please?